# Javascript. Как спарсить дату?

Tags: javascript

На сайте есть дата, она имеет значение: **20/02/2017 10:30**

Как её можно преобразовать в дату, чтобы сравнить с текущей?

Answer (score 1):

Для начала разделим строку по пробелу на две подстроки, в `tmp[0]` будет содержаться строка даты, а в `tmp[1]` - строка со временем. Дату разбиваем по `/`, а время - по `:`. Затем все это передаем конструктору `Date`.

```
var datetime = "20/02/2017 10:30";
var tmp = datetime.split(' ');
var date = tmp[0].split('/');
var time = tmp[1].split(':');
var result = new Date(date[2], date[1] - 1, date[0], time[0], time[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Можно разобрать все регуляркой

   ```
   let dateParts = /([0-9]{2})+\/([0-9]{2})\/([0-9]{4})\s([0-9]{2})\:([0-9]{2})/.exec();
   ```

Регулярку тестировать можно тут https://regex101.com/r/bZ7ZGu/2

Соответственно, начиная с индекса 1 все будет в массиве dateParts

Далее, собираем объект даты:

```
let dateObj = new Date(dateParts[3], parseInt(dateParts[2]) - 1, dateParts[1], dateParts[4], dateParts[5], 0, 0);
```

2. Способ более понятный и простой, разбиение через split()
   let dateString = '20/02/2017 10:30';
   let dateParts = dateString.split(' ')[0].split('/');
   let timeParts = dateString.split(' ')[1].split(':');

Аналогично, собираем объект даты

```
let dateObj= new Date(dateParts[0], parseInt(dateParts[1]) - 1, dateParts[2], timeParts[0], timeParts[1], 0, 0);
```

Если есть возможность, дополните в вопросе, какой именно javascript вы используете: браузерный или серверный (nodejs и т.д.)

Answer (score 0):

Решил с помощью библиотеки moment.js

```
var time = moment(stringtime, "DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm");
```